# Cannot symbolicate iOS crash report based on archive of distributed version

Tags: xcode, ios7, crash-reports, debug-symbols, dsym

I am dealing with a situation where my app works in development mode but can crash in the version that appeared on the App Store. If I download the app from App Store I can reproduce the crash.

I can see both the submitted `*.xcarchive` archive  and `*.crash` crash report in Xcode 5.1’s Organizer (under the “Archives” and “Devices” tabs respectively), however the crash report is not symbolicated. Selecting the crash report and selecting Re-Symbolicate does not help.

If I follow Apple’s instructions under [How to Match a Crash Report to a Build](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1765/_index.html) I observe that the UUID in the crash report is the same as the UUID for armv7s in the app binary. The crash occurred on an iPhone 5s, so that seems fine.

I currently have a total of three archives for that app in Xcode. The offending one is in the middle.

How I can I get Xcode to symbolicate the crash file correctly?

Comment: I am also seeing problems with symbolicating in Xcode 5.1.1. The crash log from the 7.1.1 user came as a .ips file. Symbolicate never gets any of my or the system library symbols. I noticed in the console that Stderr for [symbolicatecrash] reported a lot of "Did not find executable for dsym ## Warning Can't find any unstripped binary that matches version..."

Comment: @Viktorianec I ended up using [`atos`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/atos.1.html), which is slightly inconvenient but does the job.